# Excel VBS ERROR: relation "andmebaas" does not exist

Tags: excel, postgresql, vbscript

I am using Excel 2019 Home and Business

I have built SQL string what works if I use it trough PGAdmin, but if I execute it trough vbs i get relation error.
This is how I create connection

```
db.Open "DSN=" & databaseSource & "; Database=" & databaseName & "; Uid=" & databaseUsername & "; Pwd=" & databasePassword
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.ActiveConnection = db
```

this is the SQL string I am trying to execute. Same string works if used trough PGAdmin

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO public.kaup (grupp2, nimi, yhik, viit, grupp1, algyhik, suurus, kaal, baasyhik, tootjamaa, taimoot, teema, varvikood, brand, liik,  nimetus, tellitav, varviryhm, kollektsioon) VALUES (" & setT("brand") & ", " & Chr(39) & setName & Chr(39) & ", " & setT("unit") & ", " & setT("isRecipe") & ", " & setT("mainGroupNr") & ", " & setT("algyhik") & ", " & setT("size") & ", " & totalWeightStr & ", " & setT("baasyhik") & ", " & setT("origin") & ", " & setT("taimoot") & ", " & setT("season") & ", " & setT("factoryColor") & ", " & setT("categoryNr") & ", " & setT("productTypeNr") & ", " & setT("factoryName") & ", " & setT("orderable") & ", " & setT("colorGroup") & ", " & setT("collection") & ")"
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    cmd.Execute
```

String looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.kaup (grupp2, nimi, yhik, viit, grupp1, algyhik, suurus, kaal, baasyhik, tootjamaa, taimoot, teema, varvikood, brand, liik,  nimetus, tellitav, varviryhm, kollektsioon) VALUES (186, 'Nord Active Plus Set Safari + Granite Chassis', 'TK', 1, 2, 'tk', 'N/A', 9.5, 'PCE', 'PL', 'ZZZ', '2020', 166, 2, 885, 'Nord Active Plus Set', 1, 15, null)
```

I assume I need to add some tables in SQL string, but how would I do that in vbs?
The Table andmebaas is located in 3 different schemas.

Also I removed one another problematic column because in Database it has this written in Create table.

If i add k_m_vaba in my code ith will say it has no relation to kaup_kaibemaks

```
CONSTRAINT kaup_kaibemaks FOREIGN KEY (k_m_vaba)
        REFERENCES eesti.kaibemaks (kaibemaks) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        NOT VALID,
```

**How do I add more connections or relations in my SQL string so that when INSERT new row It knows where are these tables located at?**

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. before executing query had to set path to one of the other schemas.
Then Database was able to figure out all the other schemas by itself.

```
SET search_path TO eesti,public; INSERT INTO kaup (...
```